# How do I install a Left 4 Dead 2 server on debian?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

I have been searching for a guide on how to set up a Left 4 Dead 2 Steam dedicated server on a clean debian install.

But I haven't found one that worked.

So if anyone have successfully set up a server on debian could you please make a simple guide or link to an existing guide.

Comment: You may find it easier to look up "Left 4 dead server Linux"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all install steam, or the Half Life Dedicated Server (a.k.a. hldsupdatetool, see [This site](http://llbb.wordpress.com/2007/02/20/installing-hlds-on-linux/))

```
wget http://www.steampowered.com/download/hldsupdatetool.bin
```

Install it `./hldsupdatetool.bin` after `chmod +x` if necessary. It will put steam in the current directory.

Check the tool is at the last version with `./steam` (multiple times if necessary, until it displays the help message).

Then the install a game just do well with

```
./steam -command update -game "left4dead2" -dir .
```

(It will install l4d2 in the current directory, creating `left4dead2/` subdir.)

Hint: the game names can be changed to another game. See the list with `./steam -command list`

Bonus: run your server in screen (within the good directory)

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m -S l4d2-server ./srcds_run -console -game left4dead2 -log on -hostip 88.xxx.x.x -hostport 27016 -clientport 27006 -nohltv +exec server.cfg +map c5m1_waterfront -autoupdate
```

Comment: No need to say you need to login as root, and chmod +x on the executables (steam, hldsupdatetool.bin) to perform these steps.

You might also need to install/update your 32bit gcc libraries, since the installer is 32 bit and it is dynamically linked to 32 bit libraries.

aptitude (or apt-get) install lib32gcc1 should solve this problem.

Comment: @Bora I do not recall using root privileges to install steam, but I did it in a user directory.

Comment: Also, if you encounter any missing libraries problem, you can pinpoint them by running [ldd](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ldd.htm)

Comment: That's the best way, imho, too. Just make sure the user has enough privileges to read files from the shared library folders.